# Is there a quick method to calculate the eigenvalues of this complex $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix given below.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1 \\ 1 & i & -1 & -i \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -i &-1 &i\end{pmatrix}$

We can calculate $\det{(A-tE)}$ by the Laplace expansion(or cofactor expansion), but that method takes too much time for me. Since this question is from an exam question, I need a quick(and preferably easy) method to calculate the eigenvalues.

Of course, I have seen these questions:

[Eigenvalues for $4\times 4$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755987/eigenvalues-for-4-times-4-matrix)

[Quick method for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors in a symmetric $5 \times 5$ matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816087/quick-method-for-finding-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-in-a-symmetric-5-times-5?rq=1)

However, the answers there do not seem to be applicable to our matrix. Is there any method that can be applied to our matrix?

Comment: If only it were $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1 \\ 1 & i & -1 & -i \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -i &-1 &i\end{pmatrix}$$ That would be easy!

Comment: @AnginaSeng Oops, I rechecked the matrix, and the one you wrote was the correct one. What's the method?

Comment: Look at $A^2{}$.

Comment: Does this relate to Quantum computing for entangled qubits ?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi No, the original question is from [here](https://www.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/edu/entra/examarchive_e.shtml). 2019, question 1.

Comment: Actually it does relate to the Gate Mechanics, i just checked my notes. And thank you for the source of the examination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A^2=\pmatrix{4\\ &&&4\\ &&4\\ &4}$ are $4,4,4,-4$. Therefore three of the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm2$ and the remaining one is $\pm2i$. Since the trace of $A$ is $2+2i$, the four eigenvalues must be $2,2,-2,2i$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** One has $$A^4 = 16 I_4$$