# Is all of eigenvalues of $A^n$ in a form $\lambda^n$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is related to this question:

[Is there a quick method to calculate the eigenvalues of this complex $4 \times 4$ matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3803817/691829)

Let $A$ be a complex square matrix. In one of the answers, they used eigenvalues of $A^2$ to calculate eigenvalues of $A$. I have a question in terms of this.

We can easily show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. So, in set notation, If $\{\lambda_1,\cdots \lambda_k\}$ is a set of eigenvalues of $A$,

$\{\lambda_1^n,\cdots,\lambda^n_k\}\subset \{\textrm{Set of eigenvalues of }A^n\}$

holds. My question is, **does $\{\lambda_1^n,\cdots,\lambda^n_k\}=\{\textrm{Set of eigenvalues of }A^n\}$ hold?** If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: If $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)$ then $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ where $D^n=diag(\lambda_1^n,\dots,\lambda_p^n)$

Comment: You can count eigenvalues with multiplicities (in the finite dimension case). But beware that $\lambda^n$ has $n^{th}$ roots other than $\lambda$. In the simplest case $(-1)^2=1=1^2$ and it is not the case that both the options $\pm 1$ will be eigenvalues, nor is it necessarily the principal value of the root (here $+1$) which will be the eigenvalue you are looking for.

Comment: @Smilia you could probably do this with Jordan normal form as well

Comment: @user376343 The question was not that all the roots of the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are eigenvalues of $A$, but that all the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are nth powers of the eigenvalues of $A$. Mark Bennet's remark is true, I agree.

Comment: Thanks @Gribouillis , it was apparently a missunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$.
The following polynomial factors into its roots: $$x^n-\mu = (x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$$ $$\therefore \lambda^n-\mu = (\lambda-\alpha_1)\cdots(\lambda-\alpha_n)$$ $$\mathrm{and\ }A^n-\mu = (A-\alpha_1)\cdots(A-\alpha_n)$$
Since $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$, $A^n-\mu$ is singular, so one of the factors $(A-\alpha_i)$ is also singular. This means $(A-\alpha_i)v=0$, so $\alpha_i=\lambda$, one of the eigenvalues of $A$. Hence the right side of the middle equation is zero for that $\lambda$, and so $\mu=\lambda^n$.

Comment: Undoubtly the shortest proof.

Answer (score 2):

The result is true:

Let ${\mathbb C}^d = \oplus V_{\lambda_i}$ be the decomposition of ${\mathbb C}^d$ as the direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces of $A$. Let $P_i$ be the spectral projection onto $V_{\lambda_i}$ in this decomposition. Finally let $x\in {\mathbb C}^d$ be such that
\begin{equation}
A^n x = \lambda x
\end{equation}
We have $A^n P_i x = P_i A^n x = \lambda P_i x$, hence $P_i x$ is either $0$ or an eigenvector of $A^n|_{V_i} = (A|_{V_i})^n = (\lambda_i I+ N)^n$ where $N$ is a nilpotent operator on $V_i$. But we have $(\lambda_i I + N)^n = \lambda_i^n I + M$ where $M$ is another nilpotent oporator, hence $M P_i x = (\lambda - \lambda_i^n)P_i x$. As $0$ is the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent operator, we have $\lambda = \lambda_i^n$.

It does not imply that the eigenvectors of $A^n$ are generalized eigenvectors of $A$ because we could have $\lambda_i^n = \lambda_j^n$ for $i\neq j$. For example if $A = \left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&-1}\right]$, then $A^2=I$ and every vector is an eigenvector of $A^2$.

**Edit** (for the questions in the comments). The direct sum decomposition means that every $x\in {\mathbb C}^d$ can be written uniquely as
\begin{equation}
x = x_1 + \ldots + x_k \qquad x_i \in V_{\lambda_i}
\end{equation}
The spectral projection $P_i$ is the map $x\mapsto x_i$. It is a linear operator in ${\mathbb C}^d$ such that $P_i^2=P_i$ and $P_i P_j = 0$ for $i\neq j$. Furthermore it commutes with $A$.

The notation $A|_{V_i}$ is the restriction of $A$ to the subspace $V_i$. Implicitly we identify the matrix $A$ as the linear function $x\mapsto A x$ from ${\mathbb C}^d$ into itself. The restriction is the same function from $V_{\lambda_i}$ to itself because we know that the $V_{\lambda_i}$ are all stable by $A$.

That $A|_{V_i} = \lambda_i I + N$ where $N$ is a nilpotent operator is a consequence of the definition of the generalized eigenspace.

Comment: Excuse me, I have several questions about your answer. (1)What does 'spectral projection' mean? (2)What does $A|_{V_i}$ mean? Is it the same as the restriction of a function? Even so, I am not sure why $A^n|_{V_i}=(A|_{V_i})^n=(\lambda_i I+N)^n$ holds.