# Eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix consisting only out of 1 and -1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find the eigenvalues of A.

---

How would it be possible to find the eigenvalues of this matrix without having to solve the characteristic equation? I already saw the question [Eigenvalues for $4\times 4$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755987/eigenvalues-for-4-times-4-matrix) but wasn't able to apply it to this one. What's the easiest way to find the eigenvalues (they are $2$ and $-2$)?

Comment: $\frac12A$ is orthogonal. Its only possible eigenvalues are?

Comment: @KurtG. In what sense do you believe this matrix is orthogonal? The determinant of this matrix is clearly not $\pm 1$.

Comment: @fantasie Let me check.

Comment: KurtG is obviously right. $\frac{1}{2}A$ is an orthogonal matrix (its columns form an  orthonormal basis), so its only eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, hence the eigenvalues of the original matrix are $\pm 2$. Just look at the columns: see that their norm is $2$ and that they are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: @fantasie . The columns of $A$ have length $2$ and pairwise scalar product zero. The determinant of $A$ is $16$. Note that I normalized $A$ by $\frac12\,.$

Comment: I think strictly speaking we only know that the eigenvalues of $\frac12A$ are potentially complex numbers on the unit circle. This matrix however is also symmetric. Therefore the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: another option: $A=  \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
0 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+ J$ where $J$ is the matrix of all ones.  These two matrices commute.  The first matrix has 2 of its eigenvalues sitting on the diagonal so the other 2 should be easy to find.  Then increment the eigenpair $(\lambda_i, \mathbf 1)\to (\lambda_i +4, \mathbf 1)$ since $\text{trace}(J)=4$ and $\text{rank}(J)=1$ (in effect this is a simultanteous diagonalization argument)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, that makes sense.